# How to reverse a string in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

So simple question, which I simply cannot solve: how to reverse a string using Freemarker?

I have tried following:

```
<#assign reversed = mystring?reverse() />
```

But strings does not have reverse method... I've also tried:

```
<#assign reversed = mystring?split("")?reverse()?join("") />
```

But apparently `split("")` is not valid freemarker syntax. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: reevrse() It doesn't exist in 2.3.

Comment: Reversing strings is, in general, much harder than you might thing. Simply reversing the sequence of `char` values is *not* valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no function built in for reversing a string. Out of curiosity, what's the use case?

As of the trick with `split`, it's a valid syntax, only as the error message says, you aren't allowed to split with an empty string. But, you are allowed split with an empty regular expression:

```
<#assign reversed = myString?split("", "r")?reverse?join("")>
```

But this is a hack of course... Generally, you are supposed to expose the extra functions you need through `TemplateMethodModelEx` objects, or through Java beans, or even static utility classes.

Comment: Thanks. I need this for reversing some parts of an email address so it's not so easy for bots to read.